# Are Compute Engine & App Engine for different usage or complementary?

Tags: cloud, google

I begin in GCP.

Are Compute Engine & App Engine for different usage or complementary ?

Are them independent solutions or are these solutions intacts between themselves ?

Thanks....

Comment: They are independent. This is pretty well documented. please post researched and concise questions, for example what you are trying to accomplish ?

Comment: i want to connect to my VM instance of the ap engine part in SSH from ly computer but I don't have the ip for the instance in the app engine

Answer (score 0):

Compute Engine provides VM instances and associated infrastructure. App Engine provides development kits to deploy applications on instances managed for you.

[App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) runs on Compute Engine instances. You can get a shell on the instances and otherwise manage them, but they are a part of an auto scaling group.